# Проблема с зависанием компьютера при зарядке на новом блоке питания

Tags: железо, ноутбук

Всем привет. У меня есть ноутбук xiaomi notebook pro 15.6. Сломался блок заярдного устройства(65w) из-за этого я купил новый, не оригинальный, мощнее предыдушего (87W).

Такое решение было принято исходя из неудобства использования китайской вилки, которая постоянно вываливалась из переходника. Также я почитал на форумах о том, что использование более мощной зарядки допустимо и ничего с батареей не будет. Но сейчас мой компьютер виснет при втыкании провода зарядки, а во время использования батареи он просто летает. Я решил поставить заряжаться комп в выключенном состоянии на какое-то время, но сейчас, при использовании мне кажется, что батарея работает гораздо меньше и она испортилась.

В чём проблема? Стоит ли использовать такой зарядник? Как убедиться, что батарея не испорчена? Большое спасибо!

прикладываю фото спецификаций батареи и зарядников(старого и нового)[image: надпись на крышке ноутбука]

[image: Новое зарядное устройство]
[image: Старое зарядное устройство]

Comment: Зарядка "фонит". С аккумулятором не должно быть проблем, но работать при шуме из электросети невозможно. ИМХО, в топку этот зарядник, лучше на оригинал потратится. Имел опыт, когда мышку компа "гасила" зарядка другого устройства. То есть, шум от плохой зарядки будет "гадить" в обе стороны: как в сеть, так и в устройство.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Формально это не ответ. Но надеюсь комментарий помог.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не имеет отношения ни к программированию ни к системному администрированию

Comment: @Air, на данный момент, насколько я понимаю, вопросы про [tag:железо] явно не запрещены к обсуждению - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1291/183314

Comment: @mymedia, это вопрос не по железу... А больше электронике...

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что батарея не портится, просто при зарядке начинает виснуть тачпад и не более того. Зарядка фонит, буду использовать оригинальную зарядку.

Также Я установил AIDA 64 чтобы посмотреть температуру процессора и прочие показатели, и всё оказалось в норме. Решил подключить мышь и в итоге комп летает, просто мне казалось из-за тачпада, что он виснет.